# Copying files with Vim's netrw on Mac OS X is broken

Tags: macos, vim, netrw

To copy a file in Vim using netrw has the following steps:

1. Select the destination directory (using `mt`)
2. Select the file to be copied (using `mf`)
3. Proceed with copying (using `mc`)

The commands to use in netrw are:

`mt` run while cursor is on top of the directory intended to be the destination
`mf` run while cursor is on top of the file intended to be copied
`mc` run while cursor is on top of the destination ("marked target") directory

If I do this on an example project, Vim will display something like:

```
Copy foo.md to : bar.md
```

Suggesting it's about to do what I want it to, but upon confirming this I get the following error:

```
1 **error** (netrw) tried using g:netrw_localcopycmd<cp>; it doesn't work!
```

I've read online that netrw is considered pretty buggy and so there doesn't appear to be much documentation or notes on how to resolve this issue.

I should be clear and state that I'm not interested in using NERDTree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've figured out the initial issue:

I had two folders `foo` and `bar` (one file in each) and I marked `foo` as the target directory and then pressed ENTER on the `bar` folder (just to have a look at the files inside it), and then pressed ENTER on `foo` (to also have a look at the files inside it). At this point I was then moving my cursor up inside the `bar` folder and pressed `mf` on the file I wanted to copy. But as far as netrw was concerned, I was still "focused" on the `foo` folder.

The solution seemed to be:

At this point (imagining I had taken the above steps until just before pressing `mf`): I should press ENTER on the `bar` folder (hiding the listed files) and then press ENTER on the `bar` folder again (now re-showing the content/listed files) and finally press `mf` on the file inside `bar` that I want to copy. **NOW** as far as netrw is concerned, I've marked the file inside the correct directory and the `mc` command will succeed.

The mistake I had made was assuming that just moving the cursor inside a folder was enough for `mf` to work. I neglected to realise that I had to be "focused" in the correct folder for the `mf` command to work.

Answer (score 13):

read more at `:help netrw-cd` to understand more about current directory and browsing directory mismatch.

you either want to press `cd` before the process or just `let g:netrw_keepdir=0` in your `.vimrc`

(the mapping used to be `c`, then it changed to `cd`)

Comment: These don't work either in neovim os x, just fyi :-|

Comment: @jm3 Just tried and it works. To be more explicit, I `mt`ed the `.` (current) directory, then `mf`ed the file I want to copy, then `cmc` and voilà.

Comment: @adrien it does not work for me also :/

Comment: @JoeCabezas I'll need more details than that. Have you created a question?

Comment: The `cmc` solution didn't work for me in Neovim 0.8 (nightly), but setting `netrw_keepdir` to `0` did the trick.